# How do I save a dynamically created UIWebView to the documents directory from loadHTMLString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UIWebView that is being populated dynamically out of the values stored in NSUserDefaults and I would like to know the best way to allow a user to save the HTML document to the documents directory via a simple save button.

I load up the HTML file with the code below and my goal is to use the variable data stored in  "pName1" as the document name if possible.

```
NSString *myHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><h1><center>My HTML content - %@</center></h1></body></html>",pName1];
[quickView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got the data in a variable whose contents you display in a UIWebView.  You can take that variable and write it straight to disk.  The key is to take advantage of the `NSString` `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` method.

Here's a ***rough*** example:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.htm", pName1];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *pathToDocumentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *htmlFilePath = [pathToDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName ];
NSError *err;
[myHTML writeToFile:htmlFilePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

See link: [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).